# jQuery - How to return value from php file and set it as a value to a textbox?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Let me start by saying I am new to using jQuery so this may seem like a dumb question. When the vin textbox focuses out it trigers the jQuery script to run.

```
$("#vin").focusout(function() {
    $("#stocknum").load("../jquery/update_stocknum.php?vin=" + $("#vin").val());
});
```

The PHP file is as follows and appears to be running correctly:

```
if(isset($_GET['vin'])){
$vin = $_GET['vin'];
if(strlen($vin) > 9) {
    $stocknum = substr($vin,-6);
    echo $stocknum;
}
```

What am i doing wrong so that I can set the value of the textbox to the what php is returning in the variable $stocknum?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I assume you're filling a text input then? `$.load` fills the innerHTML of the element, a text input requires an attribute to be set, as in `value`. Changing it to `$.get` as @MohammedAdil suggest is one of many solutions ..

Comment: I understand, i was using load to pull another listbox after the first one was populated. I wasn't familiar with the $.get but its nice to know the difference now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try -

```
$("#vin").focusout(function() {
     $.get("../jquery/update_stocknum.php?vin=" + $("#vin").val(),function(data){
        $("#stocknum").val(data);
     });
});
```

Comment: That worked great, thanks! Another question is lets say i wanted to pull in a client record and wanted the first name box to pull the value of firstname in databse, last name box to pull the lastname in the database, etc?

Comment: You can send ajax request containing all the parameters to your php and , there you can insert them into DB,,,I suggest you to post another question for your specific problem